# Laradock install PDFtk

Tags: docker, pdftk, laradock

I'm trying to install pdftk for laradock (php-fpm and workspace), but pdftk is not found for Ubuntu 20.04. So I try to create a new container, but I don't know how to call it from other containers, like php-fpm and workspace.

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04

USER root

ARG TOP_LEVEL_DIR="pdftk"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
        pdftk && \
    mkdir -p /${TOP_LEVEL_DIR}

WORKDIR /var/www
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/pdftk"]
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

```yaml
# docker-composer.yml

### pdftk ###############################################
    pdftk:
      image: pdftk
      container_name: pdftk
      build:
        context: ./pdftk
      volumes:
          - ${PWD}:/pdftk
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      tty: true
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      networks:
        - backend
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define volume `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` for `php-fpm`, not for `pdftk`, meanwhile, you'd better define volume `- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`.

Then in your `php-fpm`, you could use `docker exec -it php-fpm /usr/bin/pdftk` to call `pdftk`.

Additional, `pdftk` in fact really exist in `ubuntu:20.04`, please check again.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install pdftk
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Setting up pdftk-java (3.0.9-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/pdftk.pdftk-java to provide /usr/bin/pdftk (pdftk) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/pdftk.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/pdftk.pdftk-java.1.gz (of link group pdftk) doesn't exist
Setting up pdftk (2.02-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
$ docker run --rm -it abc:1 pdftk --version
pdftk port to java 3.0.9 a Handy Tool for Manipulating PDF Documents
Copyright (c) 2017-2018 Marc Vinyals - https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk
Copyright (c) 2003-2013 Steward and Lee, LLC.
pdftk includes a modified version of the iText library.
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Bruno Lowagie, Paulo Soares, et al.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions. There is
NO warranty, not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: You save me days of testing and searching...
Works fine the install on `php-fpm` and `workspace` containers, but before run `apt install`, I need to run `mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1` to prevent error "installed openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2".

Comment: it made my day, so many time spent trying to install snap and start snap inside docker to install snap install pdftk without success